# Do we need an [authors] tag? (And if so, can [writers] be a synonym?)

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

We already have [a meta discussion](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/68/17) about tags for individual authors, of which we now have plenty, but I just noticed that there's also an [authors](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authors) tag with 6 questions. The tag wiki excerpt says:

> For questions which are *explicitly* about the author of the work.

Well ... for questions which are explicitly about a particular author, we have the tag for that author. So the tag wiki excerpt definitely isn't what we want; however, do we want the tag itself to exist at all? (I know I could just go and edit it out of those 6 questions, but I figured we should discuss this, otherwise someone will just create it again at some point.)

**Do we want an [authors](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authors) tag? If so, what sort of questions should we use it for?**

---

On a side note (this is technically a separate request, but so closely related that I think it's justified to include it in the same meta post), we also have a [writers](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writers) tag. Just in case we decide that it *is* useful to have a tag for authors in general as well as individual author tags, **can we please merge and synonymise [writers](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writers) with [authors](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authors)?**

Comment: Only 4 of those 6 questions fit that description, 2 questions are using that tag differently.

Comment: @Helmar Yep. Like I said, I thought about retagging them, but decided to take it to meta first so that everyone can see how the tags evolved before intervention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say we give [authors](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authors) the axe. It serves no purpose because as you stated in the question, individual author-specific tags exist to categorize questions by the author of the work being discussed. The other use for these author-specific tags is in questions that ask about the literary aspects of an author's life. Either way, I'd say we delete both [authors](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authors) and [writers](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writers) from the 7 questions that currently have either of those tags.

Comment: [authors] is axed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say use [behind-the-scenes](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behind-the-scenes) it fits everything that's (properly) tagged with [authors](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authors) and [writers](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writers). Retag all the fitting questions to that and expand that tag wiki accordingly.

I'm opposed to blindly making stuff synonyms so early. Maybe we will find a useful definition of *authors* or *writers*. We won't have that many questions now that we can't have an eye on it manually for a while.

Comment: [We've talked about burninating this already..](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/338/whats-going-on-behind-the-scenes) The consensus seems to be "KILL IT WITH FIRE", so I don't think this is a good option.