# Tag synonym request: [one-100-years-of-solitude] and [100-years-of-solitude]

Tags: support, retag-request

*One Hundred Years of Solitude* by Gabriel García Márquez has one of those long names which don't fit in tags and aren't easy to shorten. One way to make it short is writing "(one) hundred' as "100". We have two options:

- [one-100-years-of-solitude](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-100-years-of-solitude), which is what I picked first, but is [awkward to read](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1485/why-is-macondo-a-city-of-mirages#comment2276_1485)
- [100-years-of-solitude](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/100-years-of-solitude), which reads better, but IMO is not as discoverable without a leading "one"

While the book has only one question now, it is one of the most celebrated Latin American works of fiction and almost certainly was a huge factor in the author getting a Nobel, so I would expect more questions about it.

Can we have a tag synonym here? Since  the "one" is needed for discoverability, the first can be a synonym of the second.

Answer (score 6):

[100-years-of-solitude](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/100-years-of-solitude) seems like the right name to me. [one-100-years-of-solitude](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-100-years-of-solitude) is just wrong: the title of the book is not *One One Hundred Years of Solitude*. [one-hundred-years-of-solitude](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-hundred-years-of-solitude) is not possible due to the tag length limit (25 characters).

A synonym that contains “one-hundred” explicitly might be useful — we could make a synonym [one-hundred-years-of-soli](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-hundred-years-of-soli) (the full title truncated to the length limit) redirecting to the more readable version.

But I question the implicit premise that we need such a tag at all. [Why should we have per-book tags at all](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362/should-we-be-tagging-questions-with-the-names-of-specific-books/373#373)? **The right tag to use here is [gabriel-garcia-marquez](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gabriel-garcia-marquez)**.

Comment: **I suggest removing the final paragraph of this answer.** It doesn't really answer the question at hand: how to name a specific tag, *given that it exists*. If you want to make the case for abolishing per-book tags, do so on a meta thread devoted to that issue (as you've already done). Including it in this answer just muddies the issue, especially where voting is concerned. For instance, my upvote is for the first two paragraphs, but someone else's downvote might be for the third.

Comment: On the other hand, the reading of "100" is somewhat flexible: "a 100" would be read "a hundred", not "a one hundred",

Comment: @Randal'Thor The final paragraph is part of this answer. We shouldn't be having this debate at all because the tag shouldn't exist.

Comment: @muru Maybe you would read it that way, but I would always read "a 100" as "a one-hundred."

Comment: @amaranth and how would you read something like "ten 100s"?

Comment: @muru "Ten one-hundreds", but I don't think I've ever seen that written anywhere, and I don't know what it would mean.

Comment: @amaranth You'd see it in cricket, where it would mean "ten centuries" (a century being a score of a hundred or more runs, but less than two hundred), and be usually read as "ten hundreds". [For example](http://www.cricket.com.au/news/feature/statistical-wrap-india-south-africa-fifth-odi-wankhede-mumbai-de-villiers-du-plessis-de-kock/2015-10-26): "... Hashim Amla, Rilee Rossouw and de Villiers scored three 100s between them..."

Comment: @muru Interesting... I suppose it's a convention that I've just never seen before.

Answer (score 0):

[one-100-years-of-solitude](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-100-years-of-solitude) sounds really awkward, and you lose discoverability past the word "one".

I think it's better to focus on opening words and the key "solitude": [one-hundred-yrs-solitude](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-hundred-yrs-solitude).

Comment: Yes, that looks good

Comment: Yeeech, please, no, don't abbreviate words unless you really have to, and if you must abbreviate, abbreviate at the end. If I type `hundred-years` or `years-of-solitude`, your proposed abbreviation won't appear.