# Can we increase the maximum tag length?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Is there any way we can increase the maximum tag length to something bigger than 25 characters?

Right now, our site tags questions by book titles. Unfortunately, many book titles are longer than twenty-five characters. This has lead to some awkward abbreviations, such as [zen-and-art-of-mc-maint](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zen-and-art-of-mc-maint)

Is there any way to increase the maximum tag length?

Comment: I was just going to add the relevant book tag to [your question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2592/why-do-vultures-unexpectidely-start-talking-in-their-eyes-were-watching-god) but got stopped by the character limit. I support this request.

Comment: Related: [Raising the 25 chars limit for tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197889/162011), as well as [Increase limit on tag length](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209248/162011)

Comment: Have you pinged a CM in the Teachers' Lounge to ask if this could even remotely be a possibility? As noted by @Cahir, it seems very likely that it couldn't, but OTOH both of those main meta posts are several years old - an eternity in internet time.

Comment: @Randal'Thor just did.

Comment: [Relevant answer on main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296669/348200)

Answer (score 19):

This can be increased, but only up to a maximum of 35 characters. This means [zen-and-the-art-of-motorcycle-maintenance](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zen-and-the-art-of-motorcycle-maintenance) is *right out*.

I increased the allowed length to 32, thus allowing [zen-and-art-of-motorcycle-maint](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zen-and-art-of-motorcycle-maint), which should be a little bit easier to recognize. This sort of compromise is likely to be common... Thus, whenever possible, try to work the name of a publication into the title or first paragraph of a question.

**As of 8-8-2017**, [tags can be up to 35 characters long everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags/299490#299490).

Comment: Thank you - this will help some. :D

Comment: _"32 characters ought to be enough for anybody"_ - Shog9, 2017.

Comment: Thanks, though :) Next for SFF?

Comment: Is this a network-wide change? If yes, feel free to share any updates [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197889/162011). If not, can this be used as a precedent by all the other sites struggling with tag length?

Comment: Why did you settle for 32 instead of the maximum of 35?

Comment: It's not network-wide, @Cahir; let's try it here for a little bit & make sure nothing breaks unexpectedly. The only other place this has been changed from the default is the Russian-language Stack Overflow, and there are a lot of other differences there too - so this is the first time it's been changed on an otherwise-standard English-language site. Also, 32 is a nice round number.

Comment: Gathering links for feature-requests for this on other sites: [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11018/31394), [Movies & TV](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2822/27759), [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497), ... (more?)

Comment: Beyond what you've listed I know of [Anime](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4060/should-we-get-the-increase-in-the-tag-length-limit), @Rand. Note that there's already something of a collection here on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags/296669#296669

Comment: Today, I noticed that 35 is still to short for [tag:strange-case-of-dr-jekyll-and-mr-hyde] (and that's still without the usual "the" at the start of the title), so I had to shorten it to [tag:strange-case-of-jekyll-and-hyde] :-/

Comment: 35 is too short for [tag:colorless-tsukuru-tazaki-and-his-years-of-pilgrimage]. Can't it even shorten it to fit without missing out major words!

Answer (score 7):

I contacted the Community Managers (the people who work for Stack Overflow the company) and they told me that while it technically is possible to implement this feature request, it was unlikely to happen, due to the fact that a huge portion of the Stack Exchange software relies on the tagging feature, and thus changing the tagging feature would result in all sorts of bugs.

So it doesn't look like this feature request will be happening anytime soon.

(Maybe it's time to [reconsider whether we want to tag questions by the titles of books at all](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/737/481).)

---

Update: the Community Managers have asked a developer to take another look to see if the feature request is possible, based on how the code currently works. I guess we'll see what happens.

Comment: _"reconsider"_ - by all means; the [previous meta](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/362/11) was inconclusive, and I pretty much disagree with every point in the highest-scoring answer.

Comment: [Re](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/736/3): things just got interesting, eh? :D