# Can we become an exception to the 5-tag limit?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Stack Exchange doesn't allow a single question to have more than 5 tags.

Here on Literature, this can be a problem and mean we need to remove tags which 'should' really be on the question. For example, I was trying to retag [this question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5818/17) properly and came up short, because there are so many different tags it should have:

- [divine-comedy](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divine-comedy), [kitab-al-miraj](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitab-al-miraj) (work tags)
- [dante-alighieri](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dante-alighieri), [al-qushairi](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/al-qushairi) (author tags)
- [italian-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italian-literature), [arabic-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arabic-literature) (language tags)
- [inspiration](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inspiration), [plagiarism](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plagiarism), or at least one of these (comparison tags)

The same problem is going to arise almost every time we have a question involving two different works from different languages, e.g. a comparative question or one about intertextuality or inspiration or plagiarism. We'd want to have work tags ([assuming the works are long](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/487/17)), author tags, language tags, *and* a tag like [intertextuality](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intertextuality) or [inspiration](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inspiration). It's impossible!

Question 1 (for the Lit.SE community): **would we like to become an exception to the 5-tag limit?**

Question 2 (for the powers that be): **would it be *possible* for the 5-tag limit to be lifted here?**

<sub>And before you say that this has been requested loads of times on different sites and never implemented: the same was true of increasing the tag length limit, and [what do you know, a network-wide change was pushed starting from Literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/761/17). *There is always hope!*</sub>

Comment: Case in point about the tag length, but good luck selling to SE *why* you desperately need more tags. I'm sure they'd rather tell you to get rid of most of the ones you tried to add to that question. ;-)

Comment: I can't imagine that it would be hard to implement technically, but I'm not very hopeful that it will be done. Do you know any other sites that would like to have it? Especially sites that have graduated?

Comment: @Christophe I think [scifi.se] would also appreciate this, although AFAIR there isn't a formal meta feature-request for it over there (probably precisely because nobody has any hope that SE would implement it).